# redirect echo in a cmd batch file to a variable fail

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, redirection, echo

I use the below function to check if echo is set on or off, and as you can see it pipes echo statuse and then uses the output to set a flag:

### **FUNCTION**

```
:echos 
echo > echo.txt & rem pipe ech status to a text file
@echo off
set _echos=yes
:: default assumption is that echo was on
CALL FileStringLength echo.txt & rem fetch string length. eq to 12 if off
IF %_strlength% EQU 12 (set _echos=no)
del echo.txt      & rem zap temporary file
set "_strlength=" & rem zap temporary variable
set "_echos"      & rem show status
IF %_echos% EQU yes (@echo on
) ELSE (
 @echo off
)
:: /echos
```

It works fine, but creating a file feels ... inelegant. so I thought, hmmm why not just do a redirection? replace the pipe with

```
>echo|set /p _str="redirect"
```

*the result is as below, and when I check the string variable it's not there:*

```
redirect
>set _str
Environment variable _str not defined
>
```

not what I wanted.
At some point, in the early hours when the mind wanders I got the result! Whoohoo! crashed beautificaly on the sofa ... but could not for the life of me remember what arcane combination of code got the redirect to work! **sigh**
anyone out there who has solved this particular problem? or was it all just a hallucination brought on by ocd in the early hours?

Comment: It's not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324404/3536342 which explains why.

Comment: thank you. Hallucination then! ... but at least there is a solution there. And at best I can get rid of that temp file jumping in and out of the folder :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function to test Echo state And assign State to Variable.
Still couldn't avoid the temporary file sadly

```
@ECHO OFF

:getstate
CALL :ECHO_STATE
ECHO Echo is %state%
DEL /Q "tempEstate.sav"
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF

:ECHO_STATE
ECHO>tempEstate.sav && FIND /I "OFF" "tempEstate.sav" >nul || Set "state=on" && GOTO :EOF

Set "state=off"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, TT3RROR, and sorry for not replying earlier - been on vac. Well, you have a more elegant solution, that's for sure! So it makes the prod code block smaller which in an interpretative engine is always a win in it's own right!

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the link @DavidPostill suggested fails in my use case, sadly.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo 111') do set "readValue=%%a"
```

However when running the solution in a batch (to capture the status of echo):

```
@echo off
echo: pre for-do
echo
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo') do set "_str=%%a"
echo: post for-do
echo
echo _str= %_str%
```

the output is:

```
 pre for-do
ECHO is off.
 post for-do
ECHO is off.
_str= ECHO is on.
```

so the question, I guess remains unresolved. I still have the rather inelegant solution, so it's not all doom and gloom!
If anyone else has some ideas, I'd be real happy to explore them :-)